# "Closest Bonuses" on bungie.net for Destiny, what is this?

Tags: destiny

On the Advisors sub-page on [Bungie.net](http://www.bungie.net), I can see the following list, under a section called "Closest Bonuses":

**Edit** The bonuses are attached to an icon signifying a type of mob, edited it into the list below.

- Glimmer Income Bonus (669 / 775 kills) - Icon: Legionary
- Resource Income Bonus (2220 / 2500 kills) - Icon: Meridian Bay
- Weapon XP Bonus (4014 / 5000 kills) - Icon: Auto Rifles
- Glimmer Income Bonus (980 / 1250 kills) - Icon: Goblin
- Glimmer Income Bonus (192 / 250 kills) - Icon: Captain
- Resource Income Bonus (1865 / 2500 kills) - Icon: Ishtar Sink

What does this signify? What happens when, say, I reach the 775 kills of the first one? Will I get a temporary bonus to glimmer income? Will I get a small item, like the [Black Wax Idol](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Wax_Idol)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bonus to glimmer income increases the amount of glimmer you get when a resource collecting item, like the [Idol](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Wax_Idol) is active and you kill the appropiate creatures. You can see your bonuses in the Grimiore.

[image]

The resource income increases the chances of more than 1 resource out of resource nodes and chests on the planet you have that bonus for.

Comment: But are they temporary? Meaning that once I've killed another 106 Legionaries, I will get a buff that makes me earn more glimmer, for a short while? Is that how this works?

Comment: No, its a permanent boost. Let's say by default you get 2 glimmer per Thrall kill while Idol is active, when you rank up the Grimiore for Thralls you now get 4, and then finally 6 glimmer per kill. (made those numbers up, but I think that's actually how it is...)

Comment: OK, so just so that I understand this correctly. Let's say I pop a black wax idol right now, and kill some Fallen. For each Fallen I get 2 glimmer. Then, at some later point, I have killed enough mobs to get one of the bonuses in that list (that would be relevant to this scenario). The next time I pop a black wax idol, I will get more than 2 glimmer for each mob. If I get another such bonus, an idol will give me even more, and so on?

Comment: And I'm assuming that the bonus I get from killing legionaries doesn't apply to all types of glimmer boosts, only those relevant for Legionaries, and *only* when killing Legionaries?

Comment: correct on both assumptions

Comment: So I have a question: The first bonus in the list, 669/775 kills, icon Legionary. Do I have to kill Legionaries to get the bonus, or will I get a bonus *for* Legionaries after having killed 106 mobs of any type, or do I have to kill Legionaries to get the bonus for Legionaries? Meaning, what does the icon signify? The target of the bonus, or the mobs I have to kill?

Comment: Just wanted to mention, the glimmer bonus is independent of the Black Wax Idol, or other glimmer increasing items.

Comment: You start off with a small bonus, but that bonus increases once you reach each tier. the first tier is 775, the next may be something like 2000 kills. The amount of kills needed depends on the enemy. Something to remember is these bonuses only come into play when the resource item is active. If you don't use the items, you will continue to get 0 glimmer from kills (excluding majors... those give base 25 always).

Comment: @Rapitor That hasn't been my experience at all. I get glimmer from enemies without having to use any items.

Comment: @Fluttershy even the [Grimiore card](http://i.imgur.com/S97i8Ch.png) says on the bonus description: "All characters earn more Glimmer when this combatatnt is killed with a Glimmer-drop consumable active". It doesn't say passively. You only get dropped Glimmer from Major enemies (yellow healthbar)

Comment: @Rapitor Huh, so it does. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out a few changes since Destiny 2.0:

Yellow-bar enemies still have the glimmer-spilling animation, but you don't actually get money for killing them anymore without a glimmer consumable active.  Now I just use that animation as a reminder to activate my consumables if I haven't yet ("Hey, look! You're missing out on getting glimmer"). Frustrating, but Guardians adapt to thrive.

Earning glimmer from killing enemies nowadays comes from equipping a Ghost Shell with a perk that can harvest glimmer from kills of a certain race of enemy (Fallen, Taken, Hive, Vex, Cabal) or in PVP against a certain class of guardian (Warlock, Titan, Hunter).

You can also use the glimmer-gathering consumables, which override the Ghost perk.  The glimmer bonus from the Grimoire is still connected to the consumables, NOT the Ghost perk.  You'll get more glimmer from using the consumables, but as they only last 10 minutes and the Ghost perk is truly passive, unless you're always on top of your timers you'll probably earn more  from Ghost glimmer harvesting, on average.

To make up for the lack of glimmer-producing yellow-bar enemies, the patrols' glimmer rewards have been increased, rewarding 250 for simple missions and 500 for VIP missions.